# Is that linear operator in $L^{2}(0,1)$ bounded?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, bounded-variation, functional-inequalities, bounds-of-integration

The question is "is the follow linear operator in $L^{2}(0,1)$ bounded?"
The linear operator is the following

$(Af)(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}\int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt , 0< x \leq 1$

i know that

$\left \| A \right \|=\frac{\left \| Af \right \|}{\left \|f  \right \|} $

And i got stucked here

$\left \| A \right \|=\frac{\int_{0}^{1}\frac{1}{x}(\left | \int_{0}^{x}f(t)dt
 \right|)^{2} dx
}{\int_{0}^{1}f(x)dx}$

my discipline is poorly formulated, the professor is teaching about linear operators in hillbert space without even commenting on the necessary mathematical background

Comment: No whining or complaining about your teachers, please! They can't defend themselves, it is undignified, and this site is not the right place, anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, applying Cauchy-Schwarz to $\int_0^xf(t)\,dt=\int_0^x1\cdot f(t)\,dt$ shows that $$\begin{align}\int_0^1|Af(x)|^2\,dx&=\int_0^1\frac1{ x}\left|\int_0^xf(t)\,dt\right|^2\,dx
\\&\le\int_0^1\int_0^x|f(t)|^2\,dt\,dx
\\&=\int_0^1\int_0^t|f(t)|^2\,dx\,dt
\\&=\int_0^1t|f(t)|^2\,dt
\\&\le\int_0^1|f(t)|^2\,dt,\end{align}$$so...

Comment: the 1 / x factor disappears because of || 1 || in inequality, brilliant. thanks